# downloading an image from internet (AsyncTask), takes too long

Tags: android

I'm using AsyncTask to perform an operation that connects to internet, download data, and then get a picture of the internet.

The image obtained from internet too, but when it takes the server to respond the application gets a FC.

How I can do to get the data AsyncTask although it takes the server?

Then I put the code I use to download the data:

```
class CargaImgs extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {

    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(imagen.this);

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog.setTitle("");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Cargando Imagen...");
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return urlImageToBitmap(imageUrl(StrUrl));
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap imagen) {
        RawBmp = imagen;
        sourceBmp = RawBmp;
        sourceBmp = redimensionarImagenMaximo(sourceBmp, screen_w, screen_h);
        imageWidth = sourceBmp.getWidth();
        imageHeight = sourceBmp.getHeight();
        showBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceBmp);
        main.invalidate();
        primera_carga = false;
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

private String imageUrl(String url) {
    Document doc = null;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    Elements div_exterior = doc.getElementsByClass("inner");
    for (Element subelementos : div_exterior) {
        Elements imgs = subelementos.getElementsByTag("img");
        StrUrlImage = imgs.get(1).attr("src");
        if (StrUrlImage == StrUrlImage2) {

        } else {
            return imgs.get(1).attr("src");
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public Bitmap urlImageToBitmap(String urlImage) {
    Bitmap mIcon1 = null;
    URL url_value;
    try {
        url_value = new URL(urlImage);
        if (url_value != null) {
            mIcon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url_value.openConnection()
                    .getInputStream());
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return mIcon1;
}
```

Comment: `main.invalidate();` - what's this?

Answer (score 0):

avoid using main.invalidate() as it paints(draw whole view again--each time you execute AsyncTask)
Rather, set bitmap to the desired view or invalidate that view only.

```
public Bitmap urlImageToBitmap(String urlImage) {
    Bitmap mIcon1 = null;
    URL url_value;
    try {
        url_value = new URL(urlImage);
        if (url_value != null) {

            URLConnection conn = url_value.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(10000);

            mIcon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(conn.getInputStream());
        }
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return mIcon1;
}
```

And regarding postExecute, if there is exception in doInBackground, it will return null, and that may lead to null pointer exception. So handle that in post execute.

Comment: Then I replace main.invalidate () (main is a imageView) by main.setImageBitmap and so would not have problems?

Comment: ya, I ope so. Please try n let us know the result.

Comment: If that also is not satisfactory, try moving RawBmp = imagen;
        sourceBmp = RawBmp;
        sourceBmp = redimensionarImagenMaximo(sourceBmp, screen_w, screen_h);
        imageWidth = sourceBmp.getWidth();
        imageHeight = sourceBmp.getHeight();
        showBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceBmp);
to doInBackground.

Comment: It works, and before too but my problem is that if you took too long to get server response jumped an exception in the function doInBackgruond.

Comment: whats the exception you are getting?

Comment: 09-18 17:39:56.826: W/System.err(4812): java.net.SocketTimeoutException
09-18 17:39:56.826: W/System.err(4812):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:491)
09-18 17:39:56.826: W/System.err(4812):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
09-18 17:39:56.826: W/System.err(4812):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)

Comment: 09-18 17:39:57.036: E/AndroidRuntime(4812): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
09-18 17:39:57.036: E/AndroidRuntime(4812): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
09-18 17:39:57.036: E/AndroidRuntime(4812):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
09-18 17:39:57.036: E/AndroidRuntime(4812):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
09-18 17:39:57.036: E/AndroidRuntime(4812):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)

Comment: 09-18 17:39:58.876: E/WindowManager(4812): Activity com.animefrontline.hnf.listaMangas has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@410e9100 that was originally added here
09-18 17:39:58.876: E/WindowManager(4812): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.animefrontline.hnf.listaMangas has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@410e9100 that was originally added here
09-18 17:39:58.876: E/WindowManager(4812):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:374)

Comment: use like this
Connection = (url_value.openConnection());connection.setTimeout(timeInMillis);mIcon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(Connection()
.getInputStream()); surround open connection with try catch n catch sockettimeoutexception n corresponding null bitmap condtn in postExecute

Comment: Well, it works, and so far have had no problems with the exception.

The part "surround open connection with try catch n catch sockettimeoutexception n corresponding null bitmap condtn in postExecute" i don't understand :S

Comment: In "onPostExecute" Nothing throws SocketTimeoutException, so do not let me apply it.